# PHP file_get_contents() and cURL both fail

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I know this is probably old-hat for many of the good folks on this forum, but after a few hours of hunting here for a solution I'm still having trouble.

I have confirmed that I can get a simple call to file_get_contents() to work:

```
$content = file_get_contents('example.com');
print $content;
```

(Outputs the contents of the site, as expected.)

And, if I plug one of the URLs generated by my script into the browser directly, that works too:

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=0&p=1&f=S&l=50&Query=AN/"allied signal" AND ((((((((CCL/29/$ OR CCL/62/$) OR CCL/165/$) OR CCL/180/$) OR CCL/236/$) OR CCL/237/$) OR CCL/241/$) OR CCL/248/$) OR CCL/417/$)&d=PTXT

(In actuality, that is generated/stored as a literal string named $url in my code.  Though, I'm noticing as I type this that the quotes are throwing off something here.  Not sure if that translates to my problem or not.)

But, when I try to combine the two it fails immediately:

```
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    print $content;
```

(Outputs nothing.)

I've tried every suggestion I've seen so far involving various uses of cURL instead, and of course json to try to get some clue what is happening.  But, other than the one case where I got HTTP 400 to spit out, and another where the output was NULL (sorry, I lost the links to the specific posts I'd been reading), no luck there.

I'm sure its something ludicrously simple that I'm missing here, that I'll probably ::head desk:: when I find it, but right now I'm stuck.  Any suggestions?

Thanks In Advance

EDIT: I forgot to include, nothing in the error log either.
EDIT: allow_url_fopen is set correctly.
EDIT: Use of urlencode($url) does produce the following error, when the example above is called...
[29-May-2014 02:08:57 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO2%26Sect2%3DHITOFF%26u%3D%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm%26r%3D0%26p%3D1%26f%3DS%26l%3D50%26Query%3DAN%2F%22allied+signal%22%0D%0A+AND+%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28CCL%2F29%2F%24+OR+CCL%2F62%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F165%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F180%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F236%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F237%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F241%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F248%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F417%2F%24%29%26d%3DPTXT): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PHP-CGI\test.php on line 21

EDIT:  Some test code...

```
<?php
    print "Testing...<BR>";
    define("PATFT_head",'http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&p=1&f=S&l=50&Query=AN%2F%22');
    define("PATFT_foot",'%22+AND+%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28CCL%2F29%2F%24+OR+CCL%2F62%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F165%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F180%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F236%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F237%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F241%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F248%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F417%2F%24%29&d=PTXT');
    $assignees = file("./config/assignees.txt");
    foreach ($assignees as $name) {
    $url= PATFT_head.$name.PATFT_foot;
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    #print "Should see the page here...<BR>";
    print $content;
    }
    print "<BR>Done.";
?>
```

Contents of assignees.txt is a series of search terms (in this case the Assignee Name of a patent holder), 1 per line.

Comment: And ::head desk::  It was how I was handling the quotes in the URL.  Note the final correction to the test code above.  I guess IE/Firefox/Chrome are smarter than the PHP interpreter in this case.  Thanks to all who (tried) to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [urlencode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) :

```
  $content = file_get_content(urlencode($url));
    print $content;
```

Comment: But wait!  That does produce an error in the log, at least (edited to fit in comment): PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO2%26Sect2%3DHITOFF%26u%3D%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm%26r%3D0%26p%3D1%26f%3DS%26l%3D50%26Query%3DAN%2F%22allied+signal%22%0D%0A+AND+%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28CCL%2F29%2F%24+OR+CCL%2F62%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F165%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F180%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F236%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F237%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F241%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F248%2F%24%29+OR+CCL%2F417%2F%24%29%26d%3DPTXT): failed to open stream: Invalid argument on line 21

Comment: I think i got the problem,Try this:
$url = urlencode($url);
$url = str_replace("%2f","/",$url);
$url = str_replace("%3A",":",$url);
$content = file_get_content($url);
    print $content;

Comment: Ultimately the answer was to urlencode($name) when assigning the value to $url.  (The offending entries in the file had whitespace in the middle that I was forgetting to handle.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for allow_url_fopen in the PHP INI.  Make sure you set this to true or 1.

Comment: Another thing I forgot in the original post.  Yeah I checked that.  Actually the setting is On or Off, and if it were off the first example I gave wouldn't be working either.